# What are the current options for spending a UTxO at a script address?

Tags: utxo, multisig

If the following script is protecting a UTxO

```
{
    "type": "all",
    "scripts": [
        {
            "type": "after",
            "slot": 1000
        },
        {
            "type": "sig",
            "keyHash": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

and the slot has passed and I have the private key specified by the `keyHash` property, what are my options for spending a UTxO sitting at the script address?

I know that I can use `cardano-cli` to manually build a transaction that sends the UTxO to a wallet address I own, provide my key as a witness for the transaction and then submit it.

I am fine with doing this but **are there any other "user friendly" options for spending this UTxO for users not wanting to use the cli?**

I was hoping to find something that might allow me to tell my wallet about this script address and then have the wallet either track this address or build the transaction to "spend" the UTxO into a wallet address. I understand there could be difficulties around this for scripts requiring multiple signatures, etc. but am just looking for other currently available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be user friendly, such features would have to be implemented in wallet software like Daedalus, Nami, Eternl, etc. In principle, there is no reason why this can't be done, in fact I'd imagine someone out there has already written some simple wrapper scripts that simplify the CLI workflow. However, for real user friendliness, we'd have to wait for someone with the right shovel to come along.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I figured but wanted to see if maybe I had missed something in my research. You have been very helpful in my Cardano journey and I really appreciate it.